# Detect tablet in Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin

I am looking for a way to easily detect whether my user is on a tablet or on a fullblown pc.
Any idea how to do that?

getSession().getBrowser().isTouchDevice() won't work with more and more pc's having a touchscreen.
And getBrowser() is deprecated in Vaadin 7 anyhow.

I am not using vaadin-touchkit (should i?)

Regards, Rob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a one way for Vaadin 7:

in [UI.init()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/Page.html#init%28com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest%29) you get the parameter [VaadinRequest](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinRequest.html), which you can cast (after type check) to [VaadinServletRequest](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServletRequest.html) and use the [getHttpServletRequest](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinServletRequest.html#getHttpServletRequest%28%29) to get the underlying HTTP request. This you can then use to check the "User-Agent". 
Something like:

```
if (request instanceof VaadinServletRequest) {
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = ((VaadinServletRequest)request).getHttpServletRequest();
    String userAgent = httpRequest.getHeader("User-Agent").toLowerCase();

    // TODO: Check user agent for all tablet matching keywords
    if (userAgent.contains("ipad")) { 
        //...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the User-Agent HTTP header with

```
Page.getCurrent().getWebBrowser().getBrowserApplication()
```

It seems like there is no attribute sent in the headers to differenciate between tablet or pc but you can find out whether it's a touch screen by using.

```
if(Page.getCurrent().getWebBrowser().isTouchDevice()){ //..}
```

- getWebBrowser is not deprectated up to version 7.4.7